# Mathematical models in geology and industry

Tags: mathematical-modeling, career-development

I'm a student of applied math.  Do you think that if I attend courses on mathematical models in geology will I have the possibility to apply what I've learned in industry? I think it's a very interesting field but I've never heard of mathematicians working on "computational geology" outside academia.

Comment: Are you an undergraduate or graduate student?

Answer (score 1):

There is a great deal of mathematical modeling in industrial geology. Particularly among the large mining and oil producing companies. Of particular interest are models of seismic and electromagnetic methods of exploration.

Answer (score 1):

"A geophysicist friend once told me that geophysicists are geologists that know math."

See:

https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/265/what-is-the-difference-between-a-geologist-and-a-geophysicist

To start, try the book "An Introduction to Geophysical Exploration" by Kearey, Brooks and Hill.

http://elibrary.bsu.az/azad/new/2192.pdf